# Facebook SDK 4.23 NOT support iOS7?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7, facebook-sdk-4.0

I updated my app with Facebook SDK (ver4.23)

App works well at iPhone 6s(iOS 10.3.2) but crashed at iPhone4(iOS 7.1.2)

app crashed with this log (iOS 7.1.2)

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLQueryItem
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/ACFAA66C-9516-4E27-B6FD-2448B46F5426/Myapp.app/Myapp
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
in /var/mobile/Applications/ACFAA66C-9516-4E27-B6FD-2448B46F5426/Myapp.app/Myapp
```

I found [`NSURLQueryItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlqueryitem) supported only iOS ver 8+

and [`NSURLQueryItem`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=NSURLQueryItem&type=) is used in Facebook SDK(ver4.24) source code.

then, it means Facebook SDK ver 4.24 DOES NOT support iOS7?

plz help me;(

Answer (score 0):

the way i see it is it is not possible because the iphone 4 is limited and no longer available for updates, it is apple's policy to make you buy a new phone and toss your old one